# Is noexcept deduction allowed in class template partial specialization?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, type-traits

For the program below, Clang 5 (trunk) reports that `IsNoexcept` is not deducible, while GCC 7.1 segfaults. **What does the standard (draft) say about this?** Is this a compiler QOI issue?

```
static_assert(__cpp_noexcept_function_type, "requires c++1z");

template<typename T>
struct is_noexcept;

template<bool IsNoexcept>
struct is_noexcept<void() noexcept(IsNoexcept)> {
    static constexpr auto value = IsNoexcept;
};

static_assert(is_noexcept<void() noexcept>::value);
static_assert(!is_noexcept<void()>::value);

int main() {}
```

Relates to proposal P0012.

Comment: If a compiler seg faults while compiling, that's never a good sign. Are you going to submit a bug report?

Comment: One already exists [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80908)

Comment: Do you just want type traits to detect whether a function is `noexcept`?

Comment: @user2296177 I wrote a type trait for it [here](http://badair.github.io/callable_traits/doc/html/callable_traits/reference.html#callable_traits.reference.ref_is_noexcept), but it's broken at the moment.

Comment: why not simply do it like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fqcWXRJZFckwRgqM)?

Comment: @W.F. Doing it with a deduced bool cuts the code text in half. Not a big deal in most cases, but it's a difference of nearly 20 KLOC (preprocessed) in my library. I'm reverting back to that method, since obviously the deduced bool is not usable right now.

Comment: This is a (broken) GCC extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [[temp.deduct.type]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#8) lists all forms of types from which a template argument can be deduced. The *exception-specification* is not in the list and hence is not deducible.
2. As [an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2016-11/msg00665.html), GCC permits deducing from `noexcept` to ease the implementation of `std::is_function`. It looks like the extension is only very lightly tested.
3. The extension was first suggested by Clang's maintainer and appeared to have some support in the committee, but [it's not clear if it will eventually make its way into the standard](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32974).
4. This is not a conforming extension because it changes the meaning of well-defined code, e.g., the value of `g(f)` with the following snippet:

   ```
   void f() noexcept;

   template<bool E = false, class R>
   constexpr bool g(R (*)() noexcept(E)){
       return E;
   }
   ```

Comment: IIRC, Clang implements the deduction as a fall-back deduction: Only if `E` can't otherwise be deduced, it will deduce using the exception specification. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It's implemented [two days ago](https://reviews.llvm.org/rL304946)...I assume you are referring to the "deduced from array bound" treatment? That doesn't affect my example.

Comment: Also, that treatment only affects the type, not the value.

Comment: This is [CWG2355](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#2355) although I thought that it was adopted but now I can't find evidence thereof.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the value of the expression contained within the `noexcept` specifier does not become part of a function's type.*

N4618 §8.3.5/1 [dcl.fct] states (**emphasis mine**)

> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form 
>        `D1` ( *parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub> noexcept-specifier<sub>opt</sub>attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* 
>    and the type of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T D1` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `T`”, the type of the *declarator-id* in `D` is “*derived-declarator-type-list* `noexcept`<sub>opt</sub> function of (*parameter-declaration-clause* ) *cv-qualifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> ref-qualifier<sub>opt</sub>* returning `T`”, where the optional **`noexcept` is present if and only if the exception specification (15.4) is non-throwing**. The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* appertains to the function type.

So this means that the type of a function either includes `noexcept` or not; if the expression *expr* within `noexcept(expr)` evaluates to `false`, then the function's type will exclude the keyword `noexcept` altogether.

So you're forced to do something like this instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_noexcept
{
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_noexcept<void() noexcept> {
    static constexpr auto value = true;
};
```

However, I think that the fact that code like this compiles is misleading:

```
void (*fp)() noexcept(false);
```

Because the type of the following function:

```
void foo() noexcept(false)
{
}
```

Is `void()`.

And the type of the following function:

```
void bar() noexcept(true)
{
}
```

is `void() noexcept`

BUT, we can do this:

```
void (*fp)() noexcept(false) = &bar;
fp();
```

Even though `bar` is declared `noexcept`, we're allowed to assign the function pointer to it! So it's misleading; <strike>I can't find a standard reference for it, but it appears that the rules allow such conversions implicitly in order to accommodate an incredible amount of backwards compatibility.</strike> §5/14.2 [expr] talks about this wrt to *composite pointer types*.

Thankfully, though, this is illegal:

```
void (*fp)() noexcept(true) = &foo;
```

(See the example at N4618 §4.13 [conv.fctptr] for reference).

*integration of exception specifiers into the type system was proposed in [N4320](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4320.html) (which was adopted into the C++17 standard)